# How can I find the duplicated characters of words between 2 sentences in javascript?

Tags: javascript, filter

Is possible to return true or false if one or not of first sentence words contains in the second sentence?

Example1: **Result will be true**

- First sentence: "my name is ali"
- Second sentence: "students are: *ali*, josh, jone and tom".

Example2: **Result will be true**

- First : "tiger here"
- Second : "The lion t*here*"

Example3: **Result will be false**

- First : "open the door"
- Second : "window is closed"

Comment: Yes, it is. Try writing some code.

Comment: Yes you can. Split your string and try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
function Match(s1, s2) {
        var a = s1.split(/[, :]+/).sort();
        var b = s2.split(/[, :]+/).sort();
        var ai = 0, bi = 0;

        while (ai < a.length && bi < b.length) {
            if (a[ai] < b[bi]) { ai++; }
            else if (a[ai] > b[bi]) { bi++; }
            else /* they're equal */
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    var ss1 = 'my name is ali';
    var ss2 = 'students are: ali, josh, jone and tom';
    alert(Match(ss1, ss2));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

### Brief

The code below can be easily changed to fit your needs. The code works by concatenating your sentences using some *special character* (i.e. new line character) and then uses a regex to test your strings for a match.

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/KwgsKi/1)

```
^.*(\b\S+\b).*[\r\n].*(\1).*$
```

**The code below is auto-generated from regex101 to use the regex code above.**

```js
const regex = /^.*(\b\S+\b).*[\r\n].*(\1).*$/gmi;
const str = `my name is ali
students are: ali, josh, jone and tom
tiger here
The lion there
open the door
window is closed`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

### Notes

- I have added the case-insensitive `i` modifier so as to catch words regardless of case (i.e. `The` will match against `the`)
- The regex uses `[\r\n]` as a string separator, you can use anything here, but for viewing purposes, I've used `\r\n` as a separator.
- If you want to ensure that only full words are caught, you can change the `(\1)` to `(\b\1\b)` - this will ensure `here` will not match `there`; `here` would only match those 4 characters

---

## Edit

Just to demonstrate the simple syntax changes required to gain a result, I've added this edit.

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/KwgsKi/2)

```
^.*(\b\S+\b).*\|{3}.*(\1).*$
```

```js
const regex = /^.*(\b\S+\b).*\|{3}.*(\1).*$/gmi;
const str = `my name is ali ||| students are: ali, josh, jone and tom
tiger here ||| The lion there
open the door ||| window is closed`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Note: You can remove `^.*` from the beginning and `.*$` from the end if you're not checking multiple strings at once (`(\b\S+\b).*\|{3}.*(\1)`). These are simply added for the purpose of demonstrating this code against each string you presented in your question in one shot (posting 2 instead of 6 links).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your solutions guys. I used some parts of your codes to create my own code as I want.

```
searchByWords(s1, s2){
    if(s1==""){ //----------- In case s1 empty
        return true;
    }else{      //----------- In cass s1 not empty
        var array = s1.split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if(s2.toLowerCase().indexOf(array[i].toLowerCase())>=0){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want is to break a sentence by words into an array, you can use Javascript's `split()` function to do that. Then, just compare the arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do that in my code. I wish to get correct results

Answer (score -1):

```js
const f = (a, b) =>
 a.split(' ').some(word =>
   b.indexOf(word) !== -1)

console.log(f('my name is ali', 'students are: ali, josh, jone and tom'))
console.log(f('tiger here', 'The lion there'))
console.log(f('open the door', 'window is closed'))
```